# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 0 into shape (..). I have an array that should contain values, but it shows this error

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have multiple python files that each contain a different class. 2 of these files essentially read in a text file and do some calculations with the contents to output a .npy file that contains the new data. In these files, I first do the calculations, append each calculated line to a python list, and then convert the whole list to a numpy array to be reshaped and saved as a .npy file. The reason I reshape it is because in a different class, this array will be indexed in a certain way where I need it to be 2D.

Whenever I run the file that incorporates all the different classes, I get the following error:
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 0 into shape (36668,132)
Even though, at the end of the files where I make the numpy array, it definitely is not size 0. Another interesting thing is when I put all the classes together into one file and I make it return this numpy array BEFORE it is called by the other classes, the np.reshape works. It does not give me this error if I just run the class by itself, only when I run the whole program where it is used by another class.

Here is the code where I make the array from a list and reshape it:

```
for k in range(0, len(self.coords)):
    for i in range(0, len(self.topology)):
        if len(self.topology[i]) == 2:
            self.bat_file1.append(self.bond_length((self.coords[k][self.topology[i][0] - 1]), (self.coords[k][self.topology[i][1] -1])))
        #####etc does some more stuff###
        ### also note, this is all correctly spaced (with newlines) in the file, it may have errors here because I'm copy pasting it###

self.bat_file1 = np.array(self.bat_file1)
self.bat_file1 = np.reshape(self.bat_file1,(36668,132))
return np.save('./bat_coords.npy',self.bat_file1)
```

Here is the code where I later call this file (and another one that does the same thing but makes a smaller array) in a different file:

```
def get_top(self):
    self.non_redundant_paths = self.get_paths()
    self.temp2 = self.non_redundant_paths
    self.non_redundant_paths = self.edit_file(self.non_redundant_paths)
    f = open("./top_new", "w+")
    f.write(self.non_redundant_paths)
    bat = GETBAT1.GET_BAT("./top_new","./Cope_TS_part_BOMD_p1_36668.xyz")
    bat.read_topology()
    self.bat_coords = bat.read_topology()
    ent = ENTROPY1.Entropy("./bat_coords.npy")
    self.bat_coords = self.bat_coords.T
```

So, GETBAT1 is imported as a module, and is used to get the topology that will later be used in this class. ENTROPY1 is also a separate .py file imported as a module. I do not know why, when I use bat.read_topology() in this file it gives me an error that the numpy array is size 0.

Also, I recognize that some of this code may be redundant or poorly written. I am new to python and I will gradually be fixing this on my own. If anyone has an idea of how to fix this error, I would greatly appreciate it!!

Comment: you probably have a object dtype array containing one object,  `arr.item()` can  be used to extract this object

Comment: Make sure you understand what happens when you do `np.array(self.bat_file1)`.  What is the `shape` and `dtype` of this array?  It's hard to tell just from reading the code what `self.bat_file1` is (going into this call).  The name doesn't exactly help, since I doubt if it's an openned file, much less a file name.  And `return np.save...` doesn't do anything meaningful.  `np.save` creates a file, it doesn't return anything useful (probably just a `None`).

Comment: the type is a numpy array and shape is 36668,132. I made it print this at the end and it worked fine